# jQuery not working on IE11 but working on Chrome, Firefox and Edge?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

My scripts are working fine on all other browsers EXCEPT IE11. For example

```
jQuery('#btnblacklist').click(function(){
    jQuery('#popUpBlackList').css("display","block");
    jQuery('.cover').css('display','block');
});
```

is not returning anything on IE11. Even Microsoft Edge is okay with it.

I have already called the script in my header.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by, "it's not returning anything"?  Your function just sets css.  Any console errors?

Comment: I love this part: _I have already called the script in my header._ So where is this non-working code called?

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to JS. What I mean is, whatever function I attach to the click action on #btnblacklist is not running. For example, jQuery('#btnblacklist').click(function(){ alert('Hello World!') }) is not working as well.

Comment: Please try to place that script tag for jQuery just before the closing body tag and see if your code works then. Alternatively, you can add `defer` as an attribute to the script tag.

Comment: Randy, I tried this solution but it was of no avail. What I don't understand is, the code works perfectly well on all other browsers, except IE11.

Comment: OK...then it is a version issue probably. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Randy, ngeksyo's answer gave me a clue and I found out what's wrong. Thank you very much tho.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, you need to wrap our code in a .ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#btnblacklist').click(function () {
        jQuery('#popUpBlackList').css("display", "block");
        jQuery('.cover').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

So you're code will start to run when the document is finished loading.

Comment: Still no good. I suspect the whole external javascript is not loaded, because when I inspect #btnblacklist, it shows no event handlers registered to this element.

Comment: Please show you're code in JS fiddle, i tested that code over IE11. Also if you are running with no web server, use this in the script reference block <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> add https: and not only //

Comment: I found if I put the script directly after the element, it works! Thanks!